# Applying fast inverse to concatenated 4x4 affine transforms?

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

Is it possible to apply the fast inverse of a matrix to a concatenation of pure rotation and translation matrices, eg  `M = T2*R1*T1*R1`?

If I have a rotation and translation stored in a 4x4 homogeneous column order matrix I can say:

```
M1 = [ R1  t1 ]  given by [ 1  t1 ] * [ R1 0 ]
     [ 0    1 ]           [ 0   1 ]   [ 0  1 ]
```

and

```
inv(M1) = [inv(R1)  inv(R1)*-t1 ] given by [ 1  -t1 ] * [ inv(R1) 0 ] 
          [ 0             1     ]          [ 1    1 ] * [ 0       1 ]
```

and since R1 is rotation only we know inv(R1) = transpose(R1) so we can simply say:

```
inv(M1) = [transp(R1)  transp(R1)*-t1 ] 
          [ 0               1         ]
```

and now given some other similar rotation and translation matrix M2, if we say the concatenation of the the two in the form `MFinal = M2 * M1 = T2*R1*T1*R1`

can we say that

```
inv(MFinal) = [transp(MFinalRot)  transp(MFinalRot)*-tfinal ] 
              [ 0                             1             ]
```

where MFinalRot is the rotation part of the 4x4 matrix?

Additionally what if the order were more arbitrary for example `MFinal2 = R3*T3 * T2*R2*T1*R1` , but still only individually rotations and translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your 4x4 matrix is the concatenation of pure rotation and translation matrices, you should be able to compute a fast inverse as:

```
fast_inverse( [R1  t1] ) = [transpose(R1)  transpose(R1)*(-t1)]
              [0    1]     [     0                1           ]
```

This is because the 3x3 rotation matrix (`R1` in your code), will be a product of the input rotation matrices only, so it should itself be a rotation matrix, and its transpose should be its inverse.

If any of your concatenated matrices are scaling matrices, or if the bottom row is not `[0 0 0 1]`, then this is not true any more.

Also note that:  in practice, if you multiply enough matrices together, floating point error may cause them to "drift" some, so that they may not be as close to a proper rotation matrix as a freshly-generated one.  Depending on how you use it, this may not be a problem -- but if it is, you can "re-orthonormalize" it, as below:

```
orth(Vec3 a, Vec3 b): // return value orthogonal to b
  return (a - (dot(a,b)/dot(b,b)) * b)

re_orthonormalize(Mat3x3 Rin):
  Vec3 x = Rin.x;
  Vec3 y = orth(Rin.y, x);
  Vec3 z = orth(orth(Rin.z, x), y);
  return Mat3x3(normalize(x),normalize(y),normalize(z))
```

As long as your input isn't too far off, this should give you a proper rotation matrix.

---

To see how the `re_orthonormalize` code works, first take the dot product of the `orth` output with its `b` input.  Because the dot product is linear, we have:

```
dot(a - (dot(a,b)/dot(b,b)*b, b)
  == dot(a,b) - (dot(a,b)/dot(b,b)) * dot(b,b)
  == dot(a,b) - dot(a,b)
  == 0
```

So, if `a` and `b` are already mostly orthogonal, `ortho(a,b)` adds a small amount of `b` to make sure the dot product really is `0`.

That means in `re_orthonormalize`, `y` is exactly orthogonal to `x`.  The tricky bit is making sure that `z` is orthogonal to *both* `x` and `y`.  This only works because we have already made sure `x` is exactly orthogonal to `y`, so adding a little bit of `y` doesn't stop `orth(Rin.z, x)` from being orthogonal to `x`.

Comment: I dont quite follow the re-orthonormalize code, but i understand the notion.  For example could I just say that I will recompute the y axis with the cross product of the x and z  and then normalize all 3 axes?  Is your re-othonormalize more correct/efficient than that?

Comment: Yes.  You need to make sure all three output vectors are orthogonal to each other, and the dot product is likely more efficient.

Comment: ok I see , additionally how do you decide when to do this? The only thing I can think of is to do this after say every X transformations where X =  ?

Comment: Well, try multiplying the result of your fast-inverse with the original.  If the result is too far off the identity matrix, you've got a problem.

Comment: But, you probably only need to do it if you're accumulating an arbitrary number of matrices.  Like if you've got a rotating cube, based on multiplying by a small rotation each frame...

Comment: added some explanation on how `re_orthonormalize` works

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of the product (P=AB) of two square matrices is in general Inv(B)*Inv(A). Rotations and translations will commute. In general you have to unwind the operations in the reverse of the order in which they were applied.

In this case though, R1*T1*R2*T2=R1*R2*T1*T2 and you can then compute the inverse of the concatenation as the inverse of the composition of the individual rotations and translations.

So yes, this is sound for pure rotations and translations.